# Problems generating Player sprite image with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am trying to run the following pytho pygame code from this tutorial https://opensource.com/article/17/12/game-python-add-a-player.
After correcting the indentation as I posted on this question ['Player' object has no attribute 'rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59700090/player-object-has-no-attribute-rect) I tried to run the python code below followed by the file tree in the local folder called `images` as shown below.
But I can't see hero.png in the game. I try also [Pygame player sprite not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50049642/pygame-player-sprite-not-appearing) .

**folder images:**

stage.png: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmyok.jpg
hero.png: https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/spellun-sprite.png

**My code:**

```
import pygame  # load pygame keywords
import sys     # let  python use your file system
import os      # help python identify your OS

'''
Create class for player
'''

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.images = []
      img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','hero.png')).convert()
      self.images.append(img)
      self.image = self.images[0]
      self.rect.x = 40
      self.rect.y = 30
#cria a classe para o player

'''
Objects
'''

# put Python classes and functions here

'''
Setup
'''
worldx = 260
worldy = 220

fps   = 40  # frame rate
ani   = 4   # animation cycles
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
#BUG REMOVIDO: BUG É ".convert()" da linha "backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','stage.png').convert())"
world    = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx,worldy])
backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','stage.png'))
backdropbox = world.get_rect()

BLUE  = (25,25,200)
BLACK = (23,23,23 )
WHITE = (254,254,254)

main = True

# put run-once code here

'''
Main Loop
'''

while main == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
            main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord('q'):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False
world.blit(backdrop, backdropbox)
# put game loop here

pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(fps)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the attribute `.rect` to `Player`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.images = []
      img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','hero.png')).convert()
      self.images.append(img)
      self.image = self.images[0]
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect() # <----
      self.rect.x = 40
      self.rect.y = 30
```

Create an instance of Player. Create a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and [`add`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.add) `palyer`:

```py
player = Player()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)
```

Use [`draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) to draw all the Sprites in the Group. `draw` makes use of the `image` and `rect` attributes of the Sprites, to draw all the Sprites in the Group:

```py
all_sprites.draw(world)
```

Respect the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

```py
while main == True:

    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
            main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord('q'):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False

    # draw background
    world.blit(backdrop, backdropbox)

    # draw scene
    all_sprites.draw(world)

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: ThankXD!!!I don't know but I must have accidentally deleted a piece of kkk code. But you were really correct in your response.